# Echoing JSON results (RIOT API)

Tags: php, json

I am still an amateur on this but I am learning really fast. I have a php index which contains a API request to RIOT's API (League of Legends). I am trying to filter results, but when I try that it gives me a blank page.

This is the code I am trying to use in order to echo json results:

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>RIOT API SBOX</title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <?php

$json = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://euw.api.pvp.net/api/lol/euw/v2.5/league/by-summoner/31827832?api_key=mykey'), true);

//print_r($json);

echo $json[0]['rank'];
echo $json[0]['tier'];
echo $json[0]['wins'];

 ?> 
 </body>
</html>
```

I have a live preview on this website: http://20ff.net/ (this link uses the code shown above)
This is the 2nd link http://20ff.net/index2.php which has `print_r($json);` enabled and all the other echoes disabled (with exact same code). In the 2nd link you can see the items on which you can create a filter. I would like to know how to get information out of this arrays and echo them. Thank you for your time helping a rookie out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably because of the ssl certificate use curl with CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER to FALSE

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://euw.api.pvp.net/api/lol/euw/v2.5/league/by-summoner/31827832?api_key=mykey');

// Set so curl_exec returns the result instead of outputting it.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
// Get the response and close the channel.
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$json = json_decode($response, true);

foreach($json as $elem){
    echo $elem[0]['name'];
    echo $elem[0]['tier'];
}
```

Comment: Dear Isaac, I am very new to this. Could you please give me a helping hand where and how to combine your code with mine? Can this be placed/merged with my code between php tags?

Comment: @floppy I just edited it to match exactly what beetween your php tags, don't forget to put you're api_key to perform the test

Comment: I literally copy and pasted your code but it returns blank page. Should I try to `var_dump($response);` ? Edit: Used var_dump on response and actually did gave me some results though I dont know how or what is actually being printed.

Comment: @floppy yes please and tell me what do you get in return

Comment: @floppy is what I see in 20ff.net is the return of my code ?

Comment: Its the exact same code only  `var_dump($response);` has been added in front of json decode

Comment: @floppy try to do echo $json[31827832][0]['rank'];

Comment: I tried, but failed. Whenever I disable the var_dump on response the page returns blank. Also tried `$json[31827832]['rank'];` cuz `31827832` is the array you are already looking for i suppose. but not working either. Also tried other stuff to look for like `leaguePoints`. But also failed. Could it be because it is nested data?

Comment: @floppy I edited again my code can you put it again on 20ff.net so that I can see how to make it work ;)

Comment: @floppy put this at the beggining of your php file `ini_set("display_errors", "1");
error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: result: Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in /hermes/bosoraweb130/b411/ipg.notsureifpossiblecom/index.php on line 22

Comment: @floppy my mistake I change the code needed to add true to json_decode     `$json = json_decode($response, true);`

Comment: I tried to use multiple echoes but seems it errors pretty hard there already. 

`echo $elem[0]['rank'];` `echo $elem[0]['leaguePoints'];`

do not seem to work, as the error points out. What could this be?

Comment: @floppy to be able to access [leaguePoints] you need first to be in [entries] try this `echo $elem[0][entries][0][leaguePoints];`

Comment: Thank you, I have added apostrophes and it worked. `echo $elem[0]['entries'][0]['leaguePoints'];` I start to understand how the API works faster and faster, thanks to you!